# Right way to design database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
Country table
  country_id,country_name

State table
  state_id,state_name,state_country_id

City table
  city_id,city_name,city_state_id

Product table
  product_id,product_name,product_city_id
```

Is the above design good?
If i want to retrieve product country id then i have to write sub queries or inner join.

or can i modify product table as below?

```
Product table
  product_id,product_name,product_city_id,product_state_id,product_country_id
```

Comment: No you will make redundancy there , existing structure looks fine , just create some views for detailed data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggestion violates 3NF (assuming your candidate keys are the obvious ones). 3NF states (given wikipedias definition, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_forms#Normal_forms) that:

"Every non-prime attribute is non-transitively dependent on every candidate key in the table. The attributes that do not contribute to the description of the primary key are removed from the table. In other words, no transitive dependency is allowed."

In your proposed modification product_id is the candidate key, but product_country_id is transitively dependent of product_id

That said there are situations where you for practical reasons may choose to violate normal forms, but you should be aware of that you are doing that, and take extra precaution against update anomalies.

Side note: IMO it is also better to use standard identifiers such as country_code instead of country_id, see ISO 3166 ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3 )

Answer (score 1):

The second design (single table) allows you to create a product record against a city that is in a totally unrelated state, i.e. Moscow, Hawaii.

Therefore the second design is bad (is not normalised)

You should not be avoiding using joins in a relational database. Thats the whole point.